# How do I set onlytopic.in.map to prevent HTML files from being generated from shared content?

Tags: html, xslt, ant, dita, dita-ot

I'm using DITA OT 3.7.1 with a custom plugin to generate HTML5 documentation. When we used DITA OT 3.2.1 with the same plugin, HTML files were not generated for topics that were only used for content references and are not linked in the map. When we upgraded to DITA OT 3.6.1, HTML files were generated for these topics, and users were able to find them in our output.

I've been looking for a way to change our custom plugin to prevent those topics from being generated as HTML files. The closest solution is to set onlytopic.in.map to true. The problem is making this setting stick. Even if I change it in orgs.dita.base\build_init.xml, the HTML files are still generated for the topics that are not in the map. Of course, I would rather override it in our plugin and not change the core DITA OT. FYI, we're using map-first preprocessing with the preprocess2 target.

(Yes, I know we can add the topics to the map and set them to resource-only and toc=no. Some of our help systems have dozens of conref-only topics, and we're trying to avoid changing source files.)

Any suggestions on fixing this are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Take care,
Matt Stern
Sr. Principal Technical Writer
Kofax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to guess what's the problem, without looking at the code. You should read through the [migration guides](https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/migrating-to-3.7.html). I guess it is related to XSLT pipelines or the new `<ditafileset>` technique.

Comment: I looked through the migration guides as we were upgrading our plugins to new DITA OT versions. I made the changes for `<ditafileset>` to copy files like graphics and CSS to the output, but it doesn't prevent the generation of files. The only thing that works consistently is adding files to the map and setting them to resource-only and toc=no. Perhaps this is the preferred way to do this.

Comment: Probably yes. If you don't need the files, you might want to add an Ant target to the publishing chain to clean them up. But it seems that everything is working as it should.